# How to automatically update a site with some other site contents.?

Tags: html-content-extraction

How to update a site with some other site contents that is getting refreshed often (may be twice in a minute)?

Comment: A lot depends on the stack you are using. Is the the site you want to refresh based on ... PHP? Perl? JSP? Something else? IIS based? Apache based? What level of control/access do you have regarding the site you want to copy from?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is called scraping a website. Try googling on that. Pay particular attention to the laws around it. If you're benefiting the company you're scraping, they'll probably help you; if you're not, they'll probably sue you.

Comment: +1, screen scraping. There might be a possibility you can find similar providers of the information you need that expose web services.

Answer (score 0):

[$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is your friend. The following JQuery-function call will replace the current value of element (e.g. div) with the id "result" with the content of page "ajax/test.html".

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

or with an additional success handler:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

if you would like to call one of these function every n seconds, use the following code:

```
setInterval(function() {
  // wrap one of the above calls
}, <n>000);
```

edit:
for a cross-domain-solution, you can write a proxy page on your site which, upon call, loads the content of the 'other site' and echoes it.

Snippet available here: http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216729.html

Comment: This will only work if you reference a page within your site, not a different site though.

Comment: added comment for a cross-domain solution (one site on domain a getting content of another site on domain b), so now it works in such a szenario, too! :-)